# Detect Operating System From Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox

I am developing a firefox extension, i need to detect which operating system firefox is running on but i can't seem to find and info on how to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    // Returns "WINNT" on Windows Vista, XP, 2000, and NT systems;  
    // "Linux" on GNU/Linux; and "Darwin" on Mac OS X.  
    var osString = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"]  
                   .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULRuntime).OS;
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, getting os string for the new [addon-sdk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK):

```
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
const osString = Cc['@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1'].getService(Ci.nsIXULRuntime).OS;
console.log(osString);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox is moving to `web-extension` API where you can use:**

```
chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(info => console.log(info.os))
```

[Possible `os` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/PlatformOs) are: mac, win, android, cros, linux, openbsd

[Documentation for `getPlatformInfo` is here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getPlatformInfo)

**Warning:** this doesn't work from `content-script`, you will have to call your `background-script`.